# How do I remove a specific event from my gnome calendar?

Tags: gnome-calendar

For example, if I have meeting scheduled for Jan. 30, 2024 but it got cancelled, how do I remove this event from my calendar?

Lastly, is there a way to modify existing events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a set of instructions [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/calendar-usage.html.en) for using GNOME Calendar.

Specifically to your question, to delete an appointment <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the appointment in the calendar and select *Delete Appointment*, or click on the appointment and click *Delete* in the tool bar or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. If you are in the list view you can also use *Edit* ▸ *Delete Appointment*.

To modify or rather edit an appointment:

1. <kbd>Double-click</kbd> on the appointment that you want to edit in the calendar.
2. Edit the appointment (see [Adding an Appointment](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/calendar-usage-add-appointment.html.en) for the list of available options).
3. Click the *Save* button, or *File* ▸ *Save*.